# Generating XLS files with SheetJS in browser vs. nodeJS server: pros and cons

Tags: javascript, node.js, xls, sheetjs

I want to let users export some pieces of data in XLS files. I have a front-end application on Angular 9 and back-end on ExpressJS. Now I consider 2 ways to implement this with SheetJS: either create some ExportService to do it directly in the browser or implement this on the server-side and provide an API endpoint for exporting. To be more objective, I'd like to know what the community thinks: what are the pros and cons of the both ways?

My special concern is whether there are any functional limitations on what can be generated in browser vs. server. Aren't there some special features that are only available with server-side implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I can think of. Please feel free to supplement or correct this list to build a full picture.

## Client-side implementation

#### Pros:

- no need for an extra HTTP request (unless I need to fetch some extra data; in my case, I don't)
- less load on the server: everything happens on the user's machine
- it can be faster than server-side implementation when server is over-loaded or internet is slow

#### Cons:

- significantly increased bundle size: the whole SheetJS library has to be bundled
- it can be slower than server-side implementation when user's machine is slow

What am I missing?